# Zend Framework Twitter Service Requires Authentication for UserTimeline?

Tags: zend-framework, twitter

I am using the Zend_Service_Twitter class to retrieve my userTimeline, however since August, I am no longer able to use Basic Authentication. This is perfectly fine, since userTimeline does not require authentication at all.

Strange enough, Zend_Service_Twitter thinks userTimeline requires full authentication (using oAuth tokens) to retrieve an unprotected twitter userTimeline. Is there a way around this that allows me to use all the normal userTimeline twitter api variables.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this same issue - however, instead of trying to fix the broken Zend class, I just used the [Search API](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.twitter.html#zend.service.twitter.search.introduction).

```
$searchString  = 'from:leeked';
$twitterSearch = new Zend_Service_Twitter_Search('json');
$this->twitter = $twitterSearch->search($searchString, array('rpp' => 15));
```